# Simple generic function to copy one entity class to another class with identical members?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, generics

My client is currently receiving data from a WCF service as DataService.Entity. However, the client is using the data as Data.Entity. Both the WCF service and the Client are using the identical EntityFramework (on each side of the internet).

Is there a good generic function that will take in a generic source DataService.Entity and copy it memberwise to the identical entity--with the same members-- in Data?

Something like Func(TDataService.Entity, TData.Entity) ??

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try auto mapper

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TDataService, TData>();
var tData = Mapper.Map<TData>(tDataService));
```

Comment: I installed AuotMapper from Nuget, but what else needs to be done to execute the above code? I can't get VS2010 to recognize "Mapper". Thanks.

Comment: Automapper is a 3rd Party Library designed to automate some of these conversions for you.

Comment: I hope this works:this.Encounterdetails = e.Result.Select(y => 
                    {
                        Mapper.CreateMap<DataService.EncounterDetail,EncounterDetail>();
                        return Mapper.Map<EncounterDetail>(y);
                    });

Answer (score 1):

C# provides two operators: `implicit` and `explicit` which allow you to set one object equal to another object.  [Official Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39bb81c3.aspx).

The `implicit` operator allows you to set one object to another without casting first, useful when you know that the two items are completely identical i.e.

```
public class Object2 
{

    public static implicit Object2(Object1 ojbect1)
    {
        return new Object2{
            field1 = object1.field1,
            field2 = object1.field2
        }
    }

}

Object2 object2 = object1;
```

The `explicit` operator requires you to cast the objects, useful when you need to be clear that the conversion is happening, or when the objects are not exactly identical.

```
public class Object2
{
    public static explicit Object2(Object1 object1)
    {
        Object2 object2 = new Object2();
        object2.field1 = object1.field1;
        object2.field2 = object1.field2 + object1.field3;
        return object2;
    }
}

Object2 object2 = (Object2)object1;
```

Comment: That solves the casing problem, but how to create a generic function that copies each member when it is unknown ahead of time what those members are?

Comment: you said that the classes were identical; therefore, all the fields in `Object1` are always going to be the same as the fields in `Object2`, correct?

Comment: Yes. But in the above, I'm having to write out explicitly obj2.field1 = obj1.field1, which is essentially what I'm doing now in a lambda expression, and will need to be specific for each class (of which I have about 100). I am hoping for a function that can automate the copy through the class members. Thanks.

Comment: yes, using AutoMapper is probably a better choice if you are trying to automate 100 classes.